# dual boot with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install windows 7 as the second system

because, in main system already exist ubuntu with some large files and lib for kernel development for android

while if reinstall take a long time (internet in Indonesia is not too fast)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this question already exists, so i googled it to come up with this page :

[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

guesss that should provide you with an answer